# Automagically convert properties to auto getter/setter

Tags: c#, .net, regex, properties, resharper

I've generated a code base for service communication from a WSDL file which resulted in around 100 classes containing the following:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private string _someVar;

    public string SomeVar {
       get { return _someVar; }
       set { _someVar = value; }
    }

}
```

Is it possible to automagically turn everyone of them into auto properties? Maybe using ReSharper or some regex magic?

Comment: If this is generated code which doesn't need to be seen by anyone, does it matter? What's the use case for looking at the *source* here? Bear in mind that you'll presumably want to regenerate from time to time.

Comment: Op sounds like he's cleaning up hand written code.

Comment: @JonSkeet That I need to regenerate will be very unlikely, also since the WSDL is from a project I made ages ago, I want to work with the code, extend it, modify it and later, generate an updated WSDL from it.

Comment: @Les No, this is not the case, but you're right - this could be also useful for cleaning up handwritten code from a time when there weren't any auto setters / getters.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to do this once, you can let R# do it for you with a Code Cleanup action.

Right-click on the project (or solution, or single source file), select "Cleanup code..." and then use profile which includes "Use auto-property, if possible." (If you don't have such a profile already, you can edit your profiles from that dialog.)

However, I would *strongly* advise you to separate generated code from hand-written code. Make all your generated code use partial types (and potentially partial methods) - that way you can create a hand-written partial type which merges with the auto-generated code, without being in the same file. You don't need to look at the generated code, and you can replace it with another version later without worrying about any custom changes.

Answer (score 0):

The following Visual Studio regex will find the pattern you have above when plugged into the "Find & Replace" tool.

```
    private:Wh*:i:Wh*:i;:Wh*public:Wh*(:i):Wh*(:i):Wh*\{:Wh*get:Wh*\{[^\}]*\}:Wh*set:Wh*\{[^\}]*\}:Wh*\}
```

And this pattern will do the replace.

```
    public \1 \2 { get; set; }
```